# flutter how remove text underline on text selection (TextFormField)?

Tags: flutter

It is necessary to move the cursor to the end of the text, but in flutter this is strangely implemented through text selection, I do it like this

```
 textController.selection =
                TextSelection.collapsed(offset: textController.text.length);
```

it works, but when typing, it appears underlined

[image]

It is possible to somehow remove the underlining of the text, I read the documentation, but did not find it.

My  TextFormField

```
          TextFormField(
 
                        cursorColor: Colors.white,
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                        controller: textController,
                        autofocus: false,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white)),
                          filled: true,
                          isDense: true,
                          hintText:
                              'search',
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(
                            //Style of hintText
                            color: Colors.white60,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                        
                      ),
```

Comment: try InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "")

Comment: @MunsifAli I tried, the underline remains

Comment: you can add    decoration: TextDecoration.none inside style

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
TextField(
         style: const TextStyle(
         decoration: TextDecoration.none),
         ),
```